# Access internal transform data from Alembic FileCache

Tags: python, alembic

When importing an alembic file with streaming data I get both a MeshSequence modifiers and object transform data.

In a tool I'm writing I need to know the built-in transform data (object transform). Is this possible?

I guess it's possible with the Alembic python module, but that does not ship with Blender (pyalembic).